# Why am I getting no output from this java program?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am making two java classes, musician and band. I am trying to make an array that will store musicians into a band. Here is my musician class:

```
package mymusiclibrary;


public class Musician 
{
     String name;
     String genre;
     String roleInBand;   

     void setName(String name)
     {
         this.name = name;
     }

     String getName()
     {
         return name;
     }

}
```

Here is my band class:

```
package mymusiclibrary;


public class Band 
{
    String name;
    String genre;
    Musician[] listOfMusicians;
    int numberOfMusicians;
    int indexFilled = 0;

   public Band(String name, String genre, int numberOfMusicians)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.numberOfMusicians = numberOfMusicians;
        listOfMusicians = new Musician[this.numberOfMusicians];
    }

    void addMusician(Musician m)
    {
        listOfMusicians[indexFilled] = m;
        indexFilled++;
    }

    void printALLMusicians()
    {
        for(Musician m: listOfMusicians)
        {
            System.out.println("Musician: " + m.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my testHarness:

```
package mymusiclibrary;


public class MyMusicLibrary 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Band band = new Band("Oasis", "Acoustic", 2);

        Musician m = new Musician();
        m.setName("Ron Midney");
        band.addMusician(m);

        m = new Musician();
        m.setName("Tom White");

        band.addMusician(m);
        band.printALLMusicians();
    }

}
```

When I go to run this program, it doesn't return anything. Why is this? Does it have anything to do with null pointer identification?

Comment: So you have an error somewhere , this is what we have to guess ?

Comment: And also .. for me this code works perfectly and print the 2 musicians

Comment: Everything works fine, what's your problem? Clearly explain!